# Getting generated PHP td values

Tags: javascript, php, html-table, calculator, import-from-csv

I don't have much experience with Javascript or PHP so please bear with me.

For part of a website I'm trying to create a "fancy comparison calculator".

The aim is to compare new CSV data to set input data, percentage-wise, but online.

---

I started off by displaying a CSV in PHP,

But now, I'm having trouble getting the generated text that the PHP creates.

```
<td> I-WANT-THIS-GENERATED-PHP-TEXT </td>
```

Is there some way to use a function to pull the specific text from the generated tables out?

---

I then want to take that text and have it automatically entered into an "input-box" for a calculator. The calculator is written in Javascript, all it does is divide input (A), over input (B), then * 100.

(I'm comparing a manually set value-(A), to the CSV table value which will be entered as (B))

Is it possible to get the Javascript calculator input field, with

```
< input value="I-WANT-THIS-GENERATED-PHP-TEXT"........
```

Instead of

```
< input type="text" ...........
```

-----Anyone who knows about Javascript-----

Would it be possible to just make that "input box" constantly reload itself, that way it constantly gets new CSV data in the input-field (B).

Then would it be possible to make the "calculate" function of the calculator, match the refresh rate of the the updating CSV. Or just automatically calculate when a new number is entered in the (B) field

The goal is to have a constantly changing percentage, due to the changing (B) field.

---

-----Anyone who knows PHP-----

I also have a PHP calculator, would it be better in this case? 
Can I do what I described above?

---

For those just glancing the aim here is

```
( [manual input text] / [Generated PHP < td > text]) * 100 )
```

Please let me know if you would like to see my code.

Comment: @jason: it's called DOM operations: http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/introduction.html

Answer (score 0):

If your php code generates :

```
<td> I-WANT-THIS-GENERATED-PHP-TEXT </td>
```

then it's now an accessible DOM element which you can access in different ways in javascript :

1. `document.getElementsByTagName("td")[<td_index_in_actual_dom>]`
2. (if you add an id attribute to the tag) `document.getElementById('<td_id>')`
3. (with jQuery loaded) `$('#<td_id>')` or `$('.<class_attribute>')`

I would not recommend you the first way, thought, as it is a really bad practice to assume that the DOM has static elements.

Comment: #2 sounds like the way to go, ill try it out and let you know. thanks fred. 

Sorry, but would you also know how to make the calculate button "calculate", after the I-WANT-THIS-GENERATED-TEXT is placed? 

the current line of code for the button is 

<input type="button" value="Calculate &nbsp;Percent" class="btn" onmouseover="percentagep()">

Comment: sounds like you need the "onclick" event : http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp, the copyText() example may be interesting for you

Comment: Sorry, I already changed mouseover to click, that was the wrong version. The mouseclick is what hinders it from constantly updating. Is it not possible for it to automatically submit the data for calculation on page load, perhaps with a 5 second delay (so the csv data can come in), then the page will automatically refresh with jquery, starting it over.

Comment: to refresh your data with jquery, I suggest you to read about ajax, which will not reload the entire page over and over : http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/, then you could set an interval with "setInterval"